# How to handle a case in a Zend Framework 2 application, when one of multiple input items must be set?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, required, zend-inputfilter, laminas-api-tools

The ZF2 application I'm currently developing is Apigility driven, but I hade to move some `InputFilter` settings from the `module.config.php` to separate `InputFilter` files/classes.

Now I have (amongst others) the fields `CompanyId` and `UserId`. One (one and only one) of them must be set. I've tried this with a `Callback` Validator, see below. But it doesn't works: if both fields are missing, the validation doesn't get performed.

How can this problem be solved?

```
class AddressPostRequestInput implements ArraySerializableInterface {

    ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dataSet = [
            'CompanyId' => null,
            'UserId'    => null,
            'Type'      => null,
        ];
    }

    ...

    public function getInputFilter() {

        if (!$this->inputFilter) {

            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory     = new InputFactory();

            ...

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(

            ...

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'CompanyId',
            'required' => false,
            'filters' => array(
                ...
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Callback',
                    'options' => array(
                    'callback' => function ($value, $context = array()) {
                        $isValid =
                            (isset($context['UserId']) && !isset($context['CompanyId'])) ||
                            (!isset($context['UserId']) && isset($context['CompanyId']))
                        ;
                        return $isValid;
                    },
                ),
            ),

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'UserId',
            'required' => false,
            'filters' => array(
                ...
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Callback',
                    'options' => array(
                    'callback' => function ($value, $context = array()) {
                        $isValid =
                            (isset($context['UserId']) && !isset($context['CompanyId'])) ||
                            (!isset($context['UserId']) && isset($context['CompanyId']))
                        ;
                        return $isValid;
                    },
                ),
            ),
        )));

        $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can never remember quite what combination of these settings are needed but it will be something like:

```
    $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
        'name' => 'CompanyId',
        'required' => false,
        'allow_empty' => true,
        'continue_if_empty' => true,
        'filters' => array(
            ...
        ),
```

Might need to tweak slightly but should be able to do it with

continue_if_empty and allow_empty settings and the callback validator you have implemented